# Using VBA in ArcMap field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vba

I am trying to use ArcMap's Field Calculator to populate values in a column based on a value in another column.  So, in pseudo-code:

```
if [field1] = 'Foo'
  set [field2] = 'Bar'
endif
```

Something like that.  Test for 'foo' in the first attribute, and set the record's second attribute to 'bar.'  Seems like it should be pretty easy to do, but I keep receiving a "user interrupt" error every time I try running anything.  I think I have a misunderstanding of how to build VBA expressions with the Field Calculator...

Comment: What version of arcmap?  I think VBA in the field calculator got deprecated at 10.0.  [Here's](http://danieljlewis.org/2010/10/11/arcgis-10-field-calculator-and-python/) a good intro to the python calculator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
dim f2
if [field1] = "foo" then
  f2 = "bar"
end if
```

Screen shot of this being used in the field calculator.[image]